# Display event title in FullCalendar In ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

Am trying to render a generated title for FullCalendar events using the below snippet

**STATE**

```
this.state = {

      selectedDate: new Date(),

      visits: [
        {
          date: new Date('2020-03-21'),
          consumers: [
            {
              name: "Akon", paid: true
            },
            {
              name: "Malawani", paid: false
            },
            {
              name: "Ann", paid: true
            }]
        },
        {
          date: new Date('2020-03-24'),
          consumers: [
            {
              name: "Amr", paid: true
            },
            {
              name: "Anwar", paid: false
            },
          ]
        }
      ],
      events: null

    }
```

**INITIALIZING**

```
componentDidMount() {

    this.setState(
      {
        events: this.state.visits.map(function (visit) {
          let title = visit.consumers.length.toString()
          let date = visit.date
          console.log("initializing", title, date)
          return { title: title, date: date }
        }
        )
      }
    )

  }
```

yet the calendar keeps rendering an additional `2a`, am not sure what's causing this

[image]

Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

Comment: `an additional 2a` ...normally that's the start time of your event. Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/VwLEPmr . If you don't want it to show a specific time, then set `allDay: true` in the event's options. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are providing the date format without time
For Example:
2020-06-02 Only
This 2a is showing just because of that you are passing date with time to the event.